# How to find a linear transformation and prove it's one to one and onto?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

I am totally confused about this one...

Here is the question:
Let $T : \mathbb R^2 \rightarrow P^2$, where $P^2 = \{a + bt + ct^2| a,b,c \in \mathbb R\}$ be a linear transformation for which

$T [1,1] = 1-2t$      and       $T [1,-1] = t+2t^2$

a) Find $T [4,2]$

b) Is $T$ one-to-one?
c) Is $T$ onto?

Thanks!

PS $[1,1]$, $[1,-1]$ and $[4,2]$ are all $2\times 1$ column vectors

Comment: Hi. You will probably get a much better answer if you let us know what you have tried already

Answer (score 1):

Hints: for any $\;\binom xy\in\Bbb R^2\;$ , we can write

$$\binom xy=\frac{x+y}2\binom11+\frac{x-y}2\binom 1{\!\!-1}\implies$$

$$T\binom xy=\frac{x+y}2T\binom11+\frac{x-y}2T\binom1{\!\!-1}$$

You do alone the $\;1-1\;$ and onto thing...check, for example, the solution of a certain *homogeneous* linear system in two variables...

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your response! I just wondering is there any way I can find T? Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean " to find $\;T\;$"? There above it is! To know a function on a set $\;A\;$ you *must* know what that function does with **any** $\;a\in A\;$ , and that's precisely what's described above...

Answer (score 0):

Since $[4,2] = [1,1]+[1,1]+[1,1]+[1,-1]$ and since $T$ is linear, we know that
$$T[4,2] = T[1,1]+T[1,1]+T[1,1]+T[1,-1]$$
and then you just need to sub in the values given.

Regarding part b), $T$ can't be on-to because $P^2$ is three dimensional, and $\mathbb R^2$ is two dimensional.

On the other hand, $[1,1]$ and $[1,-1]$ clearly span $\mathbb R^2$, and $1-2t$ and $t+2t^2$ are clearly linearly independent (each has a power of $t$ that the other doesn't $t^0$ and $t^2$ respectively)), so the map is one-to-one